# Can a userspace process kfree() memory with GFP_USER?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a kernel module that handles IOCTL calls from userspace. One of the calls needs to return a variable length buffer from the kernel into userspace. From the module, I can `kmalloc( ..., GFP_USER)` a buffer for the userspace process to use. But, my question is, can this buffer be free'd from userspace or does it need to be free'd from kernel space?

Alternatively, is there a better way to handle data transfer with variable length data?

Comment: You cannot return a buffer this way; `GFP_USER` does something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, user space can't free kernel memory. Your module would have to offer another call / ioctl to let user space tell your kernel code to free the memory. You would also have to track your allocations to make sure to free them when the user space process exits so as not to leak memory… Also kernel memory is not swappable, if user space makes you allocate memory again and again it could run the kernel out of memory so you have to guard against that, too.

The easier method is to just let user space offer the buffer from its own memory. Include a maximum length argument in the call so that you won't write more than user space expects and return partial data or an error if the size is too small, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`GFP_USER` - means that its a kernel space memory that you can allow the user to access (used as a marker for shared kernel/user pages). note, process can sleep/block and run only in process context.

However, memory which gets allocated in the kernel space gets always get freed in the kernel space, and vis-a-vis for user space.